# Powershell - Copy files from local machine to server machine

Tags: powershell

local machine = from where you are executing command 
Server machine = where you copy files.

copy (localfile) to server machine

Answer (score 0):

You need to have administrative access on both machines.

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\\ServerB\SharedFile" -Destination "$Env:USERPROFILE" -Force -PassThru -Verbose
```

However, I do not recommend using powershell to do this. There are more reliable and easier methods. It is unlikely but this may corrupt a file.

Comment: can i copy from local computer

Comment: \\\ServerB\SharedFile  should be local file (c:\\temp\sharedfile )